# arcgis javascript Database error: Linestring or poly boundary is self-intersecting

Tags: arcgis-js-api

i`m trying to arcgis javascript FeatureLayer Eidting...

But... often edit function does not work properly.

Editing is not applied to the database.

I tested as follows.

1. featurelayer load
2. Edit start
3. Edit stop

[image]

i don`t know ... why this error occured...

i`m waiting for the answers..

Comment: Can you post some code on how you are submitting the edits?  Are you using the jsapi featurelayer.applyEdits?  If so you could pass the geometry to a geometry service and call the simplify method to make it topologically legal, and that might help. (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html#simplify or https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.geometry.geometryengine-amd.html#simplify)

Comment: Well, the error pretty much says it all - your geometry is self-intersecting therefor not correct. If you are sure that your geometry is correct, can you post a picture of it?

Answer (score 0):

My code is as follows:

esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("https://utility.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

map.on("layers-add-result", initEditing);

```
    var SIDO = new FeatureLayer("http://dev.smui.co.kr:26080/arcgis/rest/services/kios/FEATURE_LP_AA/FeatureServer/0", {`enter code here`
      mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
      outFields: ["*"]
    });


    map.addLayers(SIDO);

    function initEditing(evt) {
      console.log("initEditing", evt);
      // var map = this;
      var currentLayer = null;
      var layers = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function(result) {
        return result.layer;
        console.log("result ==== "+result);
      });
      console.log("layers", layers);

       editToolbar = new Edit(map);
      editToolbar.on("deactivate", function(evt) {
          console.log("deactivate !!!! ");
        currentLayer.applyEdits(null, [evt.graphic], null);
      });

      arrayUtils.forEach(layers, function(layer) {
        var editingEnabled = false;
        layer.on("dbl-click", function(evt) {
          event.stop(evt);
          if (editingEnabled === false) {
            editingEnabled = true;
            editToolbar.activate(Edit.EDIT_VERTICES , evt.graphic);
            pre_evt = evt.graphic;

            console.log("dbl-click  & eidt  true");
          } else {
            currentLayer = this;
            editToolbar.deactivate();
            editingEnabled = false;
            console.log("dbl-click  & eidt false ");
          }
        });
```

Comment: You may be able to alter the code to something like here, note this is untested, just consider it pseudocode: 
`editToolbar.on("deactivate", function(evt) { console.log("deactivate !!!! "); var newGeometry = geometryEngine.simplify(evt.graphic.geometry); evt.graphic.geometry = newGeometry; currentLayer.applyEdits(null, [evt.graphic], null); });` 
You will need to add "esri/geometry/geometryEngine" to your require/define

Comment: Thanks~! I will try to the test